# Inconsistent tcp_socket behavior in Erlang

Tags: c, sockets, erlang, tcpsocket

In order to read input 1 character at a time, I wrote a c program that uses `ssty raw`.

I use this `character.c` program to call an erlang file, `naive_tcp.erl` which sends a message over socket to a listening server on the same machine.

I expect this server, `naive_tcp2.erl`, to write back with 26 lines of descending integers and an 80 character long string with 2 "|" pipes in it, so that it lines up on the 80x26 terminal.

What happens instead is very inconsistent printing of data. Running `./character.c`, then pressing a key on the keyboard every few seconds, you can see the output starting with `"26"` and descending down to `"1"`, but instead you can see it descend to `"23"`, `"21"` or only `"24"`.

character.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  system ("clear");
  int c;
  /* use system call to make terminal send all keystrokes directly to stdin */
  system ("/bin/stty raw");
  while((c=getchar())!= '.') {
    char command[100];
    sprintf(command, "erl -noshell -run naive_tcp go -s erlang halt");
    system(command);
    printf("\r\n");

    /* type a period to break out of the loop, since CTRL-D won't work raw */
  }
  /* use system call to set terminal behaviour to more normal behaviour */
  system ("/bin/stty cooked");
  system ("clear");
  system ("echo ok\n");
  return 0;
}
```

naive_tcp.erl:

```
-module(naive_tcp).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
  Text = "hello",
  {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect({127,0,0,1}, 8094, []),
  send(Socket, Text).

format() ->
  format(26).
format(0) -> io:format("\r\n");
format(N) -> 
  io:format(integer_to_list(N)),
  io:format("        |                |                                                      "),
  format(N - 1).


send(Socket, Msg) ->
  inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
  gen_tcp:send(Socket, Msg),
  receive
    {tcp, Socket, <<"quit", _/binary>>} ->
      gen_tcp:close(Socket);
    {tcp, _, Res} ->      
      gen_tcp:close(Socket),
      io:format(Res ++ "\r\n")
  end.
```

naive_tcp2.erl

```
-module(naive_tcp2).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
  go(8094).
go(Port) ->
  Pid = spawn_link(fun() ->
  {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [binary, {active, false}]),
  spawn(fun() -> acceptor(Listen) end),
    timer:sleep(infinity)
  end),
  {ok, Pid}.

acceptor(ListenSocket) ->
  {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
  spawn(fun() -> acceptor(ListenSocket) end),
  handle(Socket).

format(Socket) ->
  format(26, Socket).
format(0, Socket) -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "\r\n");
format(N, Socket) -> 
  gen_tcp:send(Socket, integer_to_list(N)),
  gen_tcp:send(Socket, "        |                |                                                      "),
  format(N - 1, Socket).

handle(Socket) ->
  inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
  receive
    {tcp, Socket, <<"quit", _/binary>>} ->
      gen_tcp:close(Socket);
    {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
      % gen_tcp:send(Socket, Bin)
      % Msg = binary:bin_to_list(Bin),
      format(Socket)
  end,
  handle(Socket).
```

running `./character` and hitting keys:

```
26        |                |                                                      25        |                |                                                      24        |                |                                                      23        |                |

26        |                |                                                      25        |                |                                                      24        |                |                                                      23        |                |                                                      22        |                |                                                      21

26        |                |                                                      25        |                |                                                      24        |                |                                                      23        |                |

26        |                |                                                      25        |                |                                                      24        |                |                                                      23        |                |                                                      22        |                |                                                      21        |                |                                                      20        |                |

26        |                |                                                      25        |                |                                                      24        |                |                                                      23        |                |                                                      22        |                |                                                      21        |                |                                                      20

26        |                |                                                      25        |                |                                                      24
```

Comment: `erlang:halt()` will not wait for buffers sent. Use `init:stop()` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was using halt because init stop was so slow

Comment: You should maybe use [`gen_tcp:shutdown/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#shutdown-2) befor calling `erlang:halt/0`.